# Detect when a custom cell is selected from within the cell itself?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` (along with an XIB for layout within the storyboard designer).  I understand how the parent tableview notifies on cell selection by triggering `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but I can't seem to figure out how to catch the selection of a cell within the cell itself.  Can someone point me in the right direction here? Im using XCode 8 and Swift 2. Thanks!

Here is my simple custom cell class with the stubbed function to handle when the cell is selected:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
  func didSelect(indexPath: NSIndexPath ) {
    // perform some actions here
  }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth do you need to detect a cell that is selected from **within the cell itself**? It's a behaviour of `UITableViewDelegate`. It's not done from the default _UITableViewCell_ class. So you don't even need to have this behaviour in your custom cell class. Just use the `UITableViewDelegate`'s method and call a custom method of your custom class. That's it. Simple and clean

Comment: suggestions welcome: I have a custom cell class w/xib that I want to encapsulate with several segues to different views, on of the view I want to trigger is when the cell itself is selected.  I'd like to be able to dynamically add this custom cell to a tableview and not force the tableview/delegate to manage cell selection and subsequent triggering of my encapsulated segue & presentation of another view.  The custom cell and its behavior, segues, presentation of other views, etc should all be handled without having to wire-up and methods/callbacks/etc with the tableview.  what am I missing?

Comment: Hmmm. Now I understand your purpose. See my answer below: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41584111/3687801). I hope this will help you more than your accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you could do is listen for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on the UITableView, and then call a function in the cell. Here's an example:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    func didSelect(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // perform some actions here
    }
}
```

Then, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell {
        cell.didSelect(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, however, you are basically having your cell tell your table view something then you are having your table view turn around and tell your cell the same thing.  This produces an odd "code smell." I would recommend putting a gesture recognizer on the cell instead.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I understand what you meant. You want to perform some action from within your custom class if the cell is selected from anywhere else. Right?

There is a property in `UITableViewCell` class: `isSelected` that is **BOOL** type. Reference: [Apple Documentation Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623263-isselected)

You can check if this property is true/false by invoking *self*. Then you can perform your desired actions in your class.

Here is an example in Objective-C as I'm not very familiar with swift. But I think everyone can get this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if (self.selected) {
        NSLog(@"Whoa you selected a cell");
        // or perform your desired action
    }
}
```

Here `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method is equivalent to `setSelected(_:animated:)`(check: [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623255-setselected)) in swift and it is automatically invoked every time you select your cell from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you will need to do something like that, selection of cells can be handled by the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate). but if you insist on having the codes inside your cell class, you can call `didSelect` inside the delegate method `didSelectRowAt` like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell).didSelect(indexPath)
}
```

Usually codes to handle selection will appear directly inside this method, but you can call your cell like how I did above.